# Авторизация .Net

Tags: c#, identityserver4

У меня возник следущий вопрос: у `IdentityServer4` есть `AddSigningCredential`, который можно использовать для добавления сертификата, который, в свою очередь, подписывает токен. Расскажите, пожалуйста, поподробней зачем это и как оно работает.